# Zend form- element error addmultioption

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have been working on zend for a while now, but have come across this error " Fatal error: Call to a member function addMultiOption() on a non-object " a number of times but was easily solved by changing the element but now can't see to find a solution, and below the form the is the same code which works fine don't know whats up here. here's the code the error comes from

$first_name->addMultiOption($staff->staff_id, $staff->first_name);

Comment: Hi Programmer man :). How `$first_name` is define?

Comment: Hey DoyDoy, thanks for that I was using my table name instead of my element name. It works fine now

Comment: OK, happy for you, see you later. :) Mark as solve ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the first_name to match the element name

```
$organiser= new Zend_Form_Element_Select('organiser');
$organiser->addMultiOption($staff->staff_id, $staff->first_name);
```